# One to many with optional parent

Tags: .net-core, entity-framework-core

My Class:

```
public customer
{
  int Id;
  public string name;

  ...other
 public ICollection<Address> Addresses { get; set; } = new List<Address>();
}


public Employee
{
  int Id;
  public string name;
  public ICollection<Address> Addresses { get; set; } = new List<Address>();
}
public Address
{
  int Id;
   //other deatils
  
 public int? CustomerId { get; set; }
   public Customer Customer { get; set; } = null!;

     public int? EmployeeId;{ get; set; }
   public Employee { get; set; } = null!;

 

}
```

I am using ef core latest preview.. i have 3 table Customer , Employee and Address. Here Address is Common for both Customer and Employee.. SO i decided to address class both class ID as optional..

My question i is am doing rite or i have to do seperate address class for each..thanks in advance

Note: Customer/Employee can have multiple address but not same ( every time customer added new Address will be saved ( if same))

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is

1. Add these 3 tables in your database.
2. Open Address table designer and add relationships to link with Customer and Employee tables.
3. Use "Scaffold-Dbcontext" command in nuget package manager to generate everything automatically.

This one, you don't have to think. Just let EF core do it for you.

Comment: that's what i mean. database first approach is easier than code first approach. you dont have to think anything. using database first approach = let EFCore do and generate everything for you. your tasks will be easier and lighter for you to do if you switch to database first approach.

Comment: you just can use this and see how EFCore's models look like. then copy from EFCore's models to your code first approach model if you rather do code first approach.

Answer (score 0):

IMHO your modeling needs rethinking.

If I see your Address model it is saying this "An address can have either an Employee or a Customer or Both"

Is this the definition of address in your domain?

Certainly doesn't makes sense in real life.

<strike>Also this doesn't looks one to many to me, one to many would be "One person having multiple address"</strike>  : post your edit

Would post some modeling soon.

Comment: thanks ..An address can have either an Employee or a Customer --- an address is  not same for both

Comment: let me think something on this, and before posting any answer I would test that with code. Right now I am thinking on the lines of "Employee is a Person", "Customer is a Person", "A Person can have multiple Address" let me see how that translates to tables